# Does DDoS attacks affect victim position in search engine?

Tags: ddos

I've found most website attacked by mass DDoS has spike increase in alexa rank.
But how about the position in search engine?

Answer (score 2):

If your site responds slowly during a Google crawl, then your position is affected. Likewise, if your site is unavailable during the crawl, then your site can be temporarily removed from the listings. I'm not sure about other search engines.

Comment: What?! You mean there are *other* search engines?